# C++ Function Pointer Array with unnamed functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, anonymous

I am attempting to make an array of function pointers.

The array is going to be of quite a few functions (between 10 and 50 somewhere).

This declaration is similar to the one I'm using:

```
int (*functions[15])(int, int);
```

The issue I am encountering is that I will have to define all of these functions by hand.  This is fine; however I do not care to give a name to all of them.

None of the functions that will be in the array will be called from outside of the array.

I know I'm pushing my luck with this question, but is there a way for me to put anonymous functions (similar to delegates, I suppose) into this array?

or could I use a declaration similar to this:

```
int (*functions[15])(int, int);

(*function[0])(int x, int y)
{
    //stuff
}

(*function[1])(int x, int y)
{
    //other stuff
}
```

I hope to avoid using any C++11 with this, as well, if possible;  I understand a lot of improvements have been made with it, but I don't know if all compilers would support it yet (I intend on using multiple compilers across platforms).

Is there a way to do this without naming every single function, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Lambdas are supported in many popular [compilers](https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without anonymous functions, you need to name your functions. There's no alternative in pre C++11.